# Does anyone know where I can find old TFRs?

Tags: notam, tfr

Looking at the FAA TFR site (http://tfr.faa.gov/tfr2/list.html) I can only view current or future flight restrictions. Does anyone know of a resource where I can find past flight restrictions?

Comment: Are you interested in a specific area or US in general?

Comment: US in general. I'm mostly interested in VIP TFRs, but I haven't been able to find archived TFRs of any sort.

Answer (score 6):

As you know, a TFR is published in FDC NOTAMs, so you can use the FAA's NOTAM search tool's "Archive" mode to search for past TFRs issued via FDC NOTAMs.

Use this link (https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/nsapp.html#/). Press the Location button on the left and select "Archive Search." Then select a Date and Location designator to search for the NOTAMs (including TFRs) in effect on that date in that area.

By way of example, I did a search for Riverside Municipal Airport (KRAL) on 2/2/2016, and it returned these old NOTAMS (including TFRs).  See the California Speedway TFR.

[image: FAA's Archive NOTAM (and TFR) Search Tool]

Comment: I wish the archive search had a graphical interface with a map view, such that you could enter a date or date range  and see the TFRs on a map.